# File size information for folder object

Tags: box-api

For the Folder object, it lists files under that folder (item_collection), with file names and file IDs. It will be helpful to include also the file size, as currently one would need to query each file to get the size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. We've received a lot of requests for filtering the item collection returned in the GET /folders call, so this will help inform what we ultimately build.

Comment: Is there any way of requesting full information for a folder's children items (and not just the 'mini-file' information)?  It is extremely expensive to have to query the full info for each file.

Comment: We will be implementing a 'filter' system that lets you specify what specific fields you want instead of the mini system. This hasn't been released yet but will be before v2 is GA.

Comment: Do you know if this happened?  I can't find anything describing how to add the file size to the results.