# Box.com events API - Old events dropped from stream?

Tags: events, stream, position, box-api

I have been testing events API against a relatively new account (created June 13, 2012). Until today, calls to the events API with a stream position of 0 would return the very first events that occurred on the account. This allowed me to track all the files that had been added to my account without traversing the folder hierarchy. Starting this week, I am no longer getting events for uploads during the first few days after I opened my account. My call is as follows:

```
curl 'https://www.box.com/api/2.0/events?stream_type=changes&limit=100&stream_position=0' -L -H 'Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=xxxxx&auth_token=xxxxx'
```

Do older events get dropped from the events queue from time to time? If so, is there any way to know how far back the queue goes? (Assuming old events do get dropped, just checking the earliest item in the queue would be unreliable since, if that event is more recent than the last one I processed, it's not possible to tell whether the account has just been inactive or whether interim events have been dropped.)

Any guidance would be very much appreciated. Hopefully I'm just doing something wrong and the older events are still accessible one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events aren't maintained for the lifetime of the user's account. The specific length of time for which events are saved hasn't been specified yet as we're still looking at usage of the API, but we will indicate this before the v2 API is made GA.

Comment: Thanks much for the response, Sean. It'd be great to have an event stream that goes back to the beginning of time, but definitely reasonable that you cut if off.

Comment: It'd be great to have it start at the end instead of the beginning of time.

Comment: Right. if you want to crawl all the files you need to use the jwt service account api and the `As-User` header.